# What is the measure of angle F?

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is an isosceles triangle with base angles being the only part filled in. I have trouble understanding that if the base angles are not like terms, then how can I solve my equation (which is angle measure D equals angle measure E)? Help? [This is my triangle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umyKy.jpg) Also, I checked in the back of my math book and it told me the correct answers were either 130 degrees or 172 degrees, but I still don't understand how they came about these answers.

Comment: Those 130 and 172 degrees are possibilities for the top angle, not the base angles. (And WHY couldn't these figures be used for the base angles?)

Comment: Can you rotate your image so people can read it without turning their heads and reupload it?

Answer (score 4):

Base angles of an isoceles triangle are congruent. Therefore you get $x^2=3x+10$, which simplifies to $x^2-3x-10=0$ which after factoring yields the possibilities $x=5$ or $x=-2$, which both work.

If you plug in $x=5$, you will get that the base angles are both $25$ degrees, which means the missing angle is $150$ degrees.

If you plug in $x=-2$, you will get that the base angles are both $4$ degrees, which means that the missing angle is $172$ degrees.